# Django and React app ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: django, reactjs, apache, http, nginx

I'm runing specfic configuration. I got **django** runing on apache on address **localhost:8001** and **react app** running on nginx on **localhost:8005**. Also I use ngingx to route proxy. My biggest problem is when I try to call DRF API by React (calling `http://127.0.0.1:8001/api-token-auth/` so I got `/` at the end of the endpoint for sure) I'm getting `POST http://127.0.0.1:8001/api-token-auth/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Backend is running fine, I can use endpoint from **HTTPie** or **POSTMAN**
When I call backend by external domain name in React like 'example.com/api-token-auth/' it's working just fine. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']` or `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']` may solve your issue of connection refused in your django settings.py file.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

EDIT:

`http://' + require("os").hostname() + ':8001/` or

`http://' + require("ip").address() + ':8001/'`

Try using this while building the localhost ip. People have fixed this issue with this change.

Comment: I've added ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] at the begining of writing app so this is not an issue

Comment: does this help https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/416